# Your personal files are encrypted! Кто сталкивался?

Tags: вирусы

Сегодня с утра все файлы на сервере оказались зашифрованы. Ну и соответственно надпись что надо заплатить 1000$ за расшифровку. Может кто сталкивался с таким, и есть возможность вернуть файлы? Сервер под управлением centos

Comment: Расширения файлов какие стали?

Comment: все файлы стали с расширением .encrypted

Comment: https://support.drweb.ru/new/free_unlocker/?keyno=&for_decode=1

Comment: Презираю антивирусы. Практически уверен в том, что все вирусы как раз пишут всякие Касперские и Докторвебы дабы потом рубить бабло с лошпетов. Должно действовать святое правило: *не исполняй "левый" код*. И все будет хорошо.

Comment: @InterfaceUnknown, если у вас "дырявое" ПО (например, браузер) и вы ходите по не слишком цивилизованным местам в интернете, то ваше святое правило вас не спасет. Поэтому все-таки лучше пользоваться антивирусом (пусть даже бесплатным), чем не пользоваться им вообще. И своевременно обновлять ПО, конечно же.

Comment: @insolor У меня обычное ПО, обычный браузер, и хожу я по обычным местам. Начиная с Win98, в ОС есть средства, предупреждающие о попытках исполнить потенциально зловредный код. Мое правило никогда меня не подводило. Если быть точнее, то вирусов у меня никогда не было. И, кстати, я знаю почему. Потому что я не пользуюсь антивирусами :)

Answer (score 1):

Тут важен не столько сервер, сколько файловая система на нем. Некоторые файловые системы хранят версии файлов - тогда достаточно откатить файлы на более старую версию. То же самое можно сделать, если админ не забыл про бэкапы.

Многие вирусы шифруемый файл не перетирают, а просто удаляют после шифрования. В таком случае может помочь программа для восстановления удаленных файлов.